# c++ access error reading

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>    


#define KB_UP 72
#define KB_DOWN 80
#define KB_LEFT 75
#define KB_RIGHT 77
#define KB_ESCAPE 27
#define KB_ENTER 13


struct kimlik {
int id;
string TC;
string Ad;
string Soyad;
bool cinsiyet;
string dogumgunu;
string tel;
string eposta;
string girist;
string cıkıst;
int depozito;
int odenmis_k[12];
double endeks[12];
double fatura[12];
int oda_no;
};
struct kimlik kisi[20];
```

kisi is struct ^
I think error is under this row

```
void oku() {
cout << "okuma islemi yapiliyor";
ifstream file2;
file2.open("kisi.txt", ios::in |  ios::binary );
file2.seekg(0L, ios::beg);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
int i = 0;
    cout << "suanda cursor " << file2.tellg() << endl;


    file2.read((char *)&kisi[i], sizeof(kisi[i]));


}
```

I close the file

```
file2.close();
cout << "Islem tamamlandi";
getchar();
}



int main() {
```

if use don't use oku() there aren't any error

```
oku();
```

I am using oku

```
donus:
system("cls");
int i = 1;
int KB_code = 0;

string menu[7] = { " ","Kisi ekle","Kisi sil","Kisi duzenle","Listeleme 
1","Listeme 2","Cikis" };



while ((KB_code != KB_ESCAPE) && (KB_code != KB_ENTER))
{
    system("cls");
    for (int c = 1; c <= 6; c++) {
        if (c == i)
            cout << ">> " << menu[c] << endl;
        else
            cout << "   " << menu[c] << endl;

    }

    KB_code = _getch();


    switch (KB_code)
    {
    case KB_DOWN:
        i++;
        if (i == 7)
            i = 1;
        cout << endl << i << endl;
        break;



    case KB_UP:
        i = i - 1;
        if (i == 0)
            i = 6;

        cout << endl << i << endl;
        break;

    }


}
if (KB_code == KB_ESCAPE)
    goto bitir;

switch (i)
{
case 1:
    system("cls");
    kisi_ekle();
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "case2";
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "case3";
    break;
case 4:
    system("cls");
    listeleme1();
    break;
case 5:
    cout << "case5";
    break;
default:
    goto bitir;
    break;
}
_getch();
goto donus;
bitir:
system("pause");
```

program is working here and I push any key to close the console I take an error

```
}
```

I shared my project 
error is at void oku() beacuse when I don't use it there aren't any error. 
if I use oku(); when program finished, I take an access error reading error

**_Pnext**, 0xA3EF54

Comment: you never check whether or not the opening of the file has succeeded. I'd start from there. Also - what is `kisi`? Are you sure it's safe to write to it like you do?

Comment: What is `kisi[i]`? I would bet that it's a type whose memory you can't safely write to directly.

Comment: First debug it line by line and find the line that generated the error. Then post the whole code. what is kisi for example?

Comment: @Attersson posting the whole code is usually a bad idea. Instead, the OP should focus on posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which they failed to do as of right now

Comment: Yeah, I mean enough code to actually make sense... of course not the whole project. Right.

Comment: I debug it but bug is nowhere.  Error shown when I close the Console

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux    tanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `struct kimlik` has members of type `std::string`. You cannot simply read data from a file into a `struct` holding `std::string`, because `std::string` manages it's data internally. Depending on the implementation an `std::string` has a pointer to some data and members for data size and string length. Your code simply writes into those values, thus creating corrupt `std::string`s with dangling pointers and invalid internal states. You need to write and read each string independently using the `<<` and `>>` stream operators.

It's best to make your `struct` a `class` and create `writeToStream()` and `readFromStream()` methods in it:

```
class Kimlik {
public:
    // constructor etc.

    bool readFromStream(std::istream& s) {
        // implement reading of each member here
        // return true or false depending on whether reading succeeded or not
    }

    bool writeToStream(std::ostream& s) {
        // implement writing of each member here
        // return true or false depending on whether writing succeeded or not
    }

private:
    int          id;
    std::string  TC;
    std::string  Ad;
    std::string  Soyad;
    bool         cinsiyet;
    std::string  dogumgunu;
    std::string  tel;
    std::string  eposta;
    std::string  girist;
    std::string  cıkıst;
    int          depozito;
    int          odenmis_k[12];
    double       endeks[12];
    double       fatura[12];
    int          oda_no;
};
```

Then use those methods where applicable:

```
kisi[i].readFromStream(file2);
```

Also see [How to read and write a STL C++ string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616968/how-to-read-and-write-a-stl-c-string?rq=1)