# C++ Files from input, I can't find where my code fails

Tags: c++, string, file

I can't understand why my code can't read the filename from keyboard input, and then read the file from that name. I always fail on this can someone please help me out and link me some useful tutorials or guides?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#define LMAX 20
#define ERR1 -1
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile;
char filename[LMAX];
cout << "Insert filename :" << '\n' << endl;
int i=0;
while (filename[LMAX]!= '\0')
{
  cin >> filename[LMAX];
}
char* p1=nullptr;
p1=(char*) malloc (strlen(filename)*sizeof(char));
p1=&filename[LMAX];
infile.open("filename[LMAX]");
if(!infile.is_open())
{
  cerr << "File not found!" << '\n' << endl;
  return ERR1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#define LMAX 20
#define ERR1 -1
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile;
char filename[LMAX];
cout << "Insert filename :" << '\n' << endl;

// This is not the way to read a string
/*
int i=0;
while (filename[LMAX]!= '\0')
{
  cin >> filename[LMAX];
}
*/

// Read your filename directly using cin
cin >> filename;

// This is an unused variable
/*
char* p1=nullptr;
p1=(char*) malloc (strlen(filename)*sizeof(char));
p1=&filename[LMAX];
*/

// Why are you passing the variable name as the filename?
/* infile.open("filename[LMAX]"); */

// Pass the actual filename
infile.open(filename);

if(!infile.is_open())
{
  cerr << "File not found!" << '\n' << endl;
  return ERR1;
}
return 0;
}
```

**Aside:**

1. C++ has `std::string` to work with strings, so why stick to the old char array?
2. `cin >> filename` won't read a string with spaces. You might want to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616968/how-to-read-and-write-a-stl-c-string).

Comment: so is it allowed to insert a string with less than LMAX characters in this way? I was trying to find a way to let my code do so

Comment: @AvengerScarlet Yes, it can. What you were trying to do is actually an infinite loop.

Comment: I know it's possible to use <string> but for this exercise my professor wants us to avoid using new C++ functions and libraries, we're using hybrid codes.

Comment: @AvengerScarlet No problem, that's why I mentioned it in the *Aside* section. The corrected code will work fine.

Comment: yes I've noticed I always entered in that loop. Can you explain me why it happens please?

Comment: Copied and pasted it into my IDE (Clion) and it works fine

Comment: @AvengerScarlet `while (filename[LMAX]!= '\0')` I don't see a key in my keyboard that lets the user to enter a null character. So, it is always an infinite loop unless the default garbage value in that index is a null character. Then `cin >> filename[LMAX];`, you are always entering the character into a single index, how can it read the entire string this way?

Comment: but my file won't be opened still, why? I feel so stupid right now.

Comment: @AvengerScarlet Make sure that the file exists inside your working directory or give the path while entering the filename. You should also have the permission to access that file.